# why can't i dock the screenshot in 22.04 in favorites bar?

Tags: screenshot, docking

Why doesn't the screenshot app allow docking on the favorites bar?
Am I missing something?

Comment: unfortunately gnome-shell restricted external api access, so you cannot create a desktop file to launch it

Comment: I'm sorry am I missing something because the screenshot app is fully accessible in the Gnome Software Store and I have it pinned to the task bar on Ubuntu 22.04!

Comment: @WMRamadan there is no "Gnome Software Store" in Ubuntu 22.04. There is an "Ubuntu Software Store", and all the apps it provides are third party utilities, not the native built-in ones

Comment: @user5359531 You can install the "Gnome Software Store" on Ubuntu, just use `sudo apt install gnome-software`!

Comment: ok, it looks like the "screenshot app" you are refering to here must be different from the utility built in to Ubuntu 22.04. Seems to work as well though.

Answer (score 2):

The screenshot app in Ubuntu 22.04 is not anymore a separate tool. It is now part of Gnome Shell (very much like a third party extension, which, when installed, also becomes part of Gnome Shell).

The icon in the application overview is now similar in nature to the "Power Off" or "Log Out" icons. They do not exist in the Application overview, and can only be seen after searching. They are not represented by a `.desktop` file, but are internally provided by the shell. They do not represent separate applications, thus are never represented by an icon in the launcher and cannot be pinned.

#### Workarounds

##### Remove security and create a launcher for a `dbus` command

There is a way to start the new screenshot tool with a command. However, this requires turning of a security feature of recent versions of Gnome Shell, which prevents using commands to control the shell.

The command is:

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'Main.screenshotUI.open();'
```

([Reference](https://www.debugpoint.com/gnome-screenshot-tool-usage/))

To turn safe mode off, open the "Looking glass": type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then `lg` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>. On the "Evaluator" tab, enter the command

```
global.context.unsafe_mode = true
```

After this, the `dbus` command will work. You then can create a launcher manually like you can do for any command.

All by all, this is not recommended. A better way would be to write a Gnome Shell extension that exposes this particular d-bus call.

##### Install the old Gnome screenshot tool and pin that to the launcher

The old tool remains available and can be installed with the command `sudo apt install gnome-screenshot`. You then can pin a launcher to it on the dock as of old.

Comment: so how do you pin it somewhere where its easily accessible? I do not want to have to navigate to "Show Applications" > "Search" > "Screenshot" every time I want to take a screenshot. My keyboard does not have a "Print Screen" key either.

Comment: I quite agree, this change is infuriating and makes the software useless if you are trying to capture something in a hurry ie an error popup with a lot of verbage and code in it which you can't possiblely read quickly. So all advice gratefully received.

Comment: @DarrenWhite if you are in a hurry, the shortcut key is by far the fastest approach. But I agree: it would be better if this functionality also could be pinned as a launcher.